# How to call oracle stored function which returns table type using mybatis in spring?

Tags: spring, oracle, mybatis, stored-functions

I suffered difficulties in calling oracle stored function which returns table type value using Mybatis in Spring Tool Suite. Please look over my code below and answer to me. Thanks.

At first, this is my code in Oracle sql developer.

```
create or replace TYPE recommend_type as object
    (
        pno number,
        productthumimage varchar2(500),
        confidence number
    );
    /
create or replace TYPE recommend_table
        as table of recommend_type;
        /


create or replace function recommend_func 
    (p_startdata IN varchar2)
  return recommend_table
  is
    r_type recommend_table := recommend_table();
    v_conf tbl_confidence%rowtype;
    cnt number;

    v_pno tbl_product.pno%type;
    v_productthumimage tbl_product.productthumimage%type;
    v_confidence tbl_confidence.confidence%type;


    CURSOR recommendcursor is
    select * 
    from tbl_confidence
    where STARTDATA = p_startdata;        
  BEGIN 
    open recommendcursor;    
    cnt := 1;

    loop
      fetch recommendcursor into v_conf.startdata, v_conf.enddata, v_conf.confidence;
      exit when recommendcursor%NOTFOUND;

      select pno, productthumimage into v_pno, v_productthumimage
      from tbl_product
      where PNO = v_conf.enddata;  

      v_confidence := v_conf.confidence;

      r_type.extend;

      r_type(cnt) := recommend_type(v_pno, v_productthumimage, v_confidence);
      cnt := cnt+1;
    end loop; 

    return r_type;

end;
/
```

I can get result rows successfully in Oracle sql developer as below.

```
select *
from table(recommend_func(38));
```

Mapper.xml in Spring

```
<select id="getRecommedList" parameterType="org.ktl.domain.ConfidenceVO"
    statementType="CALLABLE" >
        {CALL RECOMMEND_FUNC
            (
                #{startdata, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
            )

        }
    </select>
```

Java bean - for in parameter and table type return value
    ( getter & setter & toString method are skipped.)

```
public class ConfidenceVO {

    private String startdata;
    private String enddata;
    private Double confidence;
    ( ... getter & setter )
}

public class RecommendVO {

    Integer pno;
    String productthumimage;
    Double confidence;

    ( ... getter & setter )
}
```

DAO code

```
public List<RecommendVO> getRecommedList(ConfidenceVO confidenceVO) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return session.selectList(namespace+".getRecommedList", confidenceVO);
    }
```

junit test code

```
@Test
public void getRecommedListTest() throws Exception {

    ConfidenceVO cVO = new ConfidenceVO();
    cVO.setStartdata("38");

    System.out.println(dao.getRecommedList(cVO));

}//
```

error text

```
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@51081592] to prepare test instance [org.ktl.test.AprioriDAOTest@623e088f]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext


This is the end. plz help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know java but I am guessing the problem is that you are trying to submit a function call. You should be just executing a SQL statement instead. The same SELECT statement that you use in SQLDeveloper.
Table functions are invoked as queries, not as function calls.

Comment: Thanks to your response. I solved the problem by adding additional table(tbl_recommend) and modifying function to procedure. and I can call oracle stored procedure using mybatis like below.
   <insert id="insertRecommedList" statementType="CALLABLE">
    
     CALL recommend_proc(#{startdata})
   </insert>
   
 
Anyway really thanks.